# Validate against all h2 tags

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am currently running

```
h2_text = d.find_element_by_xpath("//h2")

Listlinker = []
Listlinker = d.find_elements_by_xpath("//h2")

for link in Listlinker:
    print(link)
```

I would like to get all the h2 tags

Example h2
Example h2

But instead I get

```
<selenium.webdriver.support.event_firing_webdriver.EventFiringWebElement object at 0x10432cb10>
<selenium.webdriver.support.event_firing_webdriver.EventFiringWebElement object at 0x10432cad0>
```

Comment: What you get as an output is a list of objects representing matching elements. If you want to get text you can use `text` property: `for link in Listlinker: print(link.text)`

Comment: Thanks lol. Earlier I had tried d.find_elements_by_xpath("//h2").text()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify your code, this should work

```
headings = d.find_elements_by_tag_name("h2")
for heading in headings:
    print(heading.text) // prints the text inside the h2 tag
```

I can't tell from what you are asking if you are looking for the text inside or the HTML of the h2 tag. If you want the HTML of the h2 tag you can use `get_attribute("outerHTML")`.

Comment: Thank you! How would I go as to asserting against heading.text?

Comment: What type of asserts are you using? I would recommend googling the docs for the library you are using. Generally you would have a string that you are looking for (expected) and you would assert that against heading.text (actual). You'd have to give me more details if you need more guidance.

Comment: I was able to assert by adding all the h2 tags into a list and asserting against that. Thanks.